# How do I determine whether my Windows installation is 64 or 32 bit?

Tags: windows

Does anyone know how I can find this information? System properties does not specify the version, winver does not specify this either.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `Control Panel > System and Maintenance > System`

And Look at the 4th row under system

[image: Check windows architecture]

Answer (score 3):

You can see this in the system control panel applet - I see an entry "system type" there which mentions "32-bit Operating System"

Comment: In Vista and later it's more easily visible. It may be that 64-bit XP also shows it. At least 64-bit Server 2k3 does.

Answer (score 3):

Some command-line ways to get to that information:

You can take a look at the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` environment variable. This will be "x86" for a 32-bit OS and AMD64 for x86_64 (dunno the value for Itanium right now, but probably "IA64" or similar):

```
> echo %processor_architecture%
AMD64

> echo %processor_architecture%
x86
```

This even works with a 32-bit OS on a 64-bit-capable CPU.

Another way—though not in ancient versions of Windows—would be to use WMI:

```
> wmic os get OSArchitecture
OSArchitecture
64-bit

> wmic os get OSArchitecture
OSArchitecture
32-bit
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a link that successfully identifies the differences at [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827218):

> - Click Start, type system in the Start Search box, and then click system in the Programs list.
> - The operating system is displayed as follows:
>
>   - For a 64-bit version operating system: 64-bit Operating System appears for the System type under System.
>   - For a 32-bit version operating system: 32-bit Operating System appears for the System type under System.

Comment: @CaptainCasey +1 nice find